# Shuffling Algorithm for Stroop Effect

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I'm working on a small `C# Winforms` application that replicates several visual experiments concerning cognitive psychology. Instead of using premade images, I was trying to create them programmatically to train my skills.

Now I'm working on the [Stroop Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect) and I'm attempting to reproduce the following image:

[image: Example]

I prepared two distinct arrays, one containing the colors and one containing the name of the colors:

```
Color[] colors =
{
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Red,
    Color.Black,
    Color.Green
};

String[] names =
{
    "BLUE",
    "RED",
    "BLACK",
    "GREEN"
};
```

The first step is easy. All I have to do is to draw the strings using their respective `ForegroundColor`, such that `names[0]` will be printed using `colors[0]`, `names[1]` will be printed using `colors[1]` and so on...

And here comes the hard part of the task. Once the string array has been shuffled:

```
Random r = new Random();
String[] namesRandom = names.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();
```

I have to shuffle the `colors` array too. But this must be achieved making sure that **no color is being matched with its correct name**. So, for example, this will be **correct**:

```
"BLACK" Color.Green
"GREEN" Color.Red
"RED"   Color.Blue
"BLUE"  Color.Black
```

and this will be **wrong**:

```
"BLACK" Color.Black -> Matching Color/Name
"GREEN" Color.Red
"RED"   Color.Blue
"BLUE"  Color.Green
```

Any idea about how to accomplish this efficiently? I would like to avoid the `shuffle until condition is met` approach.

P.S. = drawing strings on a `Bitmap` is not a problem and I don't need help on this development task.

**[EDIT]**

For 10k-ers that downvote for not being able to associate the concept of `shuffle until condition is met` with a few lines of code or because they think I'm trying to get my work done while I play Tetris, here is a quick implementation of my current algorithm:

```
public class Program
{
    private static Random s_Random = new Random();

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Color[] colors =
        {
            Color.Blue,
            Color.Red,
            Color.Black,
            Color.Green
        };

        String[] names =
        {
            "BLUE",
            "RED",
            "BLACK",
            "GREEN"
        };

        while (MatchingPairs(colors, names)) 
        {
            colors = Shuffle(colors);
            names = Shuffle(names);
        }

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i)
            Console.WriteLine(colors[i].Name.ToUpperInvariant() + " | " + names[i]);
    }

    private static Boolean MatchingPairs(Color[] colors, String[] names)
    {
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (colors[i].Name.ToUpperInvariant() == names[i])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
        return array.OrderBy(x => s_Random.Next()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, I can use my fingers to type code. I'm just wondering if there is a better approach to obtain the same result.

Comment: Why not a class of color and name so the 2 bits of info stay together?

Comment: Well, because it's good to keep them together only when I draw matching colors / names pairs. I'm trying to see if I can avoid the "shuffle until condition is met" approach.

Comment: It would keep them together during the shuffle too which is what the question asks

Comment: But then I would end up plotting the same strings with their proper foreground color just in another position.

Comment: When you go to draw the second set, shuffle a copy of the List<T> that lacks the one just displayed.  Linq would make it trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not the best approach, but it should work fine. One way to solve this would be to assign random names until you have only two left (`where index i == Count - 2`). At that point, if the name of the item at index `i + 1` is one of the remaining choices, use that for the item at index `i`.

Here's some sample code that uses a console application (and `ConsoleColor`), but the concept is the same. I've used a class that combines a `ConsoleColor` and a `string`, so if you want to use arrays it would need some modification.

First the class:

```
class NamedColor
{
    public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public NamedColor(ConsoleColor color, string name)
    {
        Color = color;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

And a method that prints out a list of these objects to the Console:

```
static void PrintColors(IEnumerable<NamedColor> colors)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.Write(new string(' ', 80));

    foreach (var color in colors)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color.Color;
        Console.Write(color.Name + " ");
    }

    Console.Write(new string(' ', 139)); // Ugly, hard-coded length for simplicity
}
```

Then we can create a method that will take a list of these objects, shuffle all the names between them, and return that new list:

```
static NamedColor[] ShuffleNames(NamedColor[] colors)
{
    var names = colors.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
    var shuffled = new NamedColor[colors.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
    {
        string name;

        // If there are only two items left, and our list of names contains 
        // the *next* item's name, then we must take that name for this item
        if (i == colors.Length - 2 && names.Contains(colors[i + 1].Name))
        {
            name = colors[i + 1].Name;
        }
        else
        {
            // Choose a random name from all names except this item's name
            var candidateNames = names.Where(n => !n.Equals(colors[i].Name)).ToList();
            name = candidateNames[rnd.Next(candidateNames.Count)];
        }

        shuffled[i] = new NamedColor(colors[i].Color, name);
        names.Remove(name);
    }

    return shuffled;
}
```

Then we can shuffle our list, then shuffle the names, and then print out the list like so:

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var correctColors = new NamedColor[]
    {
        new NamedColor(ConsoleColor.Blue, "BLUE"),
        new NamedColor(ConsoleColor.Black, "BLACK"),
        new NamedColor(ConsoleColor.Red, "RED"),
        new NamedColor(ConsoleColor.Green, "GREEN"),
    };

    PrintColors(correctColors);

    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
    {
        // Shuffle the items, then shuffle the names
        var shuffledColors = correctColors.OrderBy(c => rnd.NextDouble()).ToArray();
        shuffledColors = ShuffleNames(shuffledColors);

        PrintColors(shuffledColors);
    }

    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

1. Implement a rule of valid colors for each name:

   ```
   Func<string, IEnumerable<Color>> validColorsRule = s =>
   {
       switch (s)
       {
           case "BLUE": return colors.Except(new[] { Color.Blue });
           case "RED": return colors.Except(new[] { Color.Red });
           case "BLACK": return colors.Except(new[] { Color.Black });
           case "GREEN": return colors.Except(new[] { Color.Green });
           default: throw new NotSupportedException();
       }
   };
   ```
2. Build the shuffled `Color` array with `Enumerable.Aggregate`:

   ```
   Color[] colorRandom =
       namesRandom.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<Color>(),
                             (acc, n) => 
                                 acc.Concat(new[] { 
                                    validColorsRule(n).Except(acc)
                                                      .OrderBy(x => r.Next())
                                                      .FirstOrDefault() }))
                  .ToArray();
   ```

Comment: Hmmm, just realized this can fail; if the shuffles fall perfectly wrong, the last assignment might not have any valid options; an easy hack is to reshuffle colors until `colorRandom` contains no `default(Color)`s, but that defeats the purpose doesn't it? (although the amount of "failed" shuffles should be quite less than your current approach)

Comment: Well, reducing the ciclomatic complexity is my objective... and this sure represents an improvement in this sense. I'm gonna run a few tests now.

Answer (score 1):

You could reformulate as a pseudo-random problem.

> 1. Generate a random integer between 1 and n-1(say i) and shift the color array(use a copy of it) by that i
> 2. Now generate a random sequence between 0 and n-1 without replacement and print the name and color

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            ConsoleColor[] colors =
       {
            ConsoleColor.Blue,
            ConsoleColor.Red,
            ConsoleColor.Black,
            ConsoleColor.Green
        };

            String[] names =
            {
            "BLUE",
            "RED",
            "BLACK",
            "GREEN"
        };

            Random r = new Random();
            int i = 0;
            while(i==0)
                i=r.Next() % (names.Length-1);
            List<int> rndList = Enumerable.Range(0,names.Length).OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToList();
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            foreach(int j in rndList)
            {
                int k = (j+i) % (colors.Length);
                Console.ForegroundColor = colors[k];
                Console.Write(names[j] + " ");
            }
}
```

Comment: Mh, can I see a coding approach? Even pseudo-code would be good enough.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo see my code sample. I am a little iffy about the modulo inside the foreach, so test it or you can recode without it

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to create a random derangement. A web search for this finds a paper about the efficient generation of such things at http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611972986.7 - "Generating Random Derangements" by Martinez, Panholzer, and Prodinger. However the paper also shows that, even as n gets possibly very large, the chance of a randomly chosen permutation being a derangement remains very close to 1/e, so the simple solution of just generating a random permutation and checking to see if it is a derangement, repeating until this is true, may in practice be efficient enough for most purposes.